# Convert Javascript current date time to UTC date time in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

I can't see a way to convert the current date/time in Javascript to a full date time in UTC. I need an equivalent to

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
```

but one that returns the UTC time in milliseconds

some thing like this

```
var UTCnow = new Date().getUTCTime();
```

I can't seem to see what I can use to make this happen in the JS Date object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

> The `getTime()` method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.
>
> `getTime()` always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, `getTime()` will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.

In other words, it already does what you are asking.

You can also do the same thing *without* instantiating a `Date` object:

```
var utcnow = Date.now();
```

Which [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) describe as:

> The `Date.now()` method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: hi Matt. maybe I don't understand something correctly. I have a date time that I save on the server, this is a UTC date time that represents 24hours from the current time, I save it in a db table. ex. 4:58 PM PST = 11:58PM UTC March 23 2018. Then when I fetch this value I pass to javascript and I have the milliseconds value. I'm trying to create a countdown to this date so I need to get the current date in utc to subtract from the utc time off the server

Comment: @user1186050 - You'll need to ask a new question then, as that's not what you asked about here.  I suggest searching first, as much has been written on this subject already.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Likely your trouble lies in the part where you describe as `"I pass to javascript"`, but you don't give any detail of that in your question here.

Comment: @jakenberg - regarding your edit, I reverted it because your assesment was not correct.  The number of milliseconds are in terms of UTC, not local time.  The MDN docs sited are correct.